# We need canonical questions for migrating DEV -> STAGING -> LIVE

Tags: discussion, canonical

I just closed *another* question that had to deal with migrating from DEV to STAGING to LIVE.  I closed it as too broad because I couldn't find any of the decent target question for closing as dup.

As I see it, we have three types of migration questions

- code
- settings
- content

The experienced people here will recognize that the first is rather easy, but the second two can be tricky.

I am proposing that we identify canonical questions for each of these cases, and then

- edit the question to make them awesome
- identify other questions with good answers that can be merged in
- vote up and down on the answers to let the good ones rise to the top

When we are done this, we can canonize them.

Thoughts?

Comment: All three borderline "primarily opinion based" problem. And we need 6 of them, not 3, as things will work significantly different in ≥8 than they do in ≤7

Comment: I would argue that they aren't necessarily opinion base, especially if the question is worded well.  Asking which method best, yeah that is all opinion.  Asking how to do it?  That is a real world problem that is very common to Drupal admins, and can garner an experience based answer.  I also think we can ignore 8 for the time being, until the dust settle there (especially since migrate-in-core is still a work in progress).

Comment: I'm not saying it is opinion based, I only say it is close, and it requires extra care when editing canonical-to-be questions.